# Showing that a complex function is bijection on a particular region in $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm finding it tricky to come up with a proof for the statement below. If anyone was able to offer some help, that would be great.

Suppose that $h \in \{z \in \Bbb{C} | \left| z \right| \lt 1 \} = A$. Show that $$f(z) = \frac{z - h}{1 - \bar{h}z}$$
is a bijection on the set A by showing that the domain of $f$ contains $A$, that $f(A) \subset A$ and that there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}$.

EDIT: The domain part isn't an issue, it is mainly the $f(A) \subset A$ that is the issue.

Thanks,
Helen

Comment: Pick an arbitrary image of $z$ and show its modulus is less than 1.

Comment: Compute $\lvert 1 - \overline{h}z\rvert^2 - \lvert z - h\rvert^2$.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, if I do this, what do I do with the result. I believe this can be factorised into the product of two differences involving $|z|$ and $|k|$.

Comment: The difference will tell you about the modulus. E.g if you have $a/b$ and you compute $b^2-a^2$ and it turns out to be positive, then b is absolutely greater than a hence the ratio is absolutely less than 1.

Comment: Ah of course, thanks very much for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

What you call $A$ is simply the (open) unit disk $\mathbb D$. Notice that $f(z)$ is undefined at $z = \frac{1}{\bar{h}}$, which lies outside $\mathbb D$ since $|h|<1$.

To show that $f(\mathbb D)\subset \mathbb D$, observe that for any $|z|=1$,

$$f(z) = \frac{|z-h|}{|1-\bar{h}z|} = \frac{1}{|z|} \frac{|z-h|}{|\bar{z}-\bar{h}|}=1 $$ where we have used $\frac{1}{z} = \bar{z}$ when $|z|=1$.

This means that $f$ has a maximum modulus of $1$ on the boundary of $\mathbb D$. What does that tell you about the values of $|f|$ inside $\mathbb D$?